# AMP Validato error: attribute '[expanded]' may not appear in tag 'amp-accordion > section'

Tags: amp-html

I want to dinamically open/close an accordion's section based on the value of a property in the state.

This is my test:

```
<amp-accordion animate>
    <section id="section_A" [expanded]="true">
      <h3>Canion</h3>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor est</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section_B" [expanded]="false">
      <h3>Canion</h3>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor est</p>
      </div>
    </section>
</amp-accordion>
```

I get this error

```
attribute '[expanded]' may not appear in tag 'amp-accordion > section
```

Weird thing is that the expanded attribute looks like a valid property of section.

This passes the AMP validation:

```
<amp-accordion animate>
    <section id="section_A" expanded>
      <h3>Canion</h3>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor est</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section_B" expanded>
      <h3>Canion</h3>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor est</p>
      </div>
    </section>
</amp-accordion>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Amp doesn't allow `[expanded]` in the `<amp-accordion>` section and you got it to work properly when followed by AMP's rules.If you want them to be in collapse state when the page first load then remove `expanded`

Comment: I want to dinamically open/close the sections based on the value of a property in the state

Comment: @IvánQuiñones AMP does not evaluate expressions on page load